# How to download shared folder from google drive without zipping?

Tags: video, shared-folders, google-drive

N.B. **The files are not in my drive so don't suggest backup & sync. I want to download multiple video files in the *shared* folder & don't wish to zip any files.**

If this community is not right for this question. Redirect me to the proper community. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google Drive doesn't allow you to request unzipped downloads.  If avoiding zip files is critical, you must use another method to download.  The simplest would be to individually download the files, using the preview menu.  If you wish, you may be able to find a thrid-party client that provides this feature.  If you have the skill, you can write a custom script on the drive API.  However, I would recommend that you simply live with the extra step of unzipping.